# Is it possible to stream Cloud Build logs with the Node.js library?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-build

**Some context:** Our Cloud Build process relies on manual triggers and about 8 `substitutions` to customize deploys to various firebase projects, hosting sites, and preview channels. Previously we used a bash script and `gcloud` to automate the selection of these substitution options, the "updating" of the trigger (via `gcloud beta builds triggers import`: our needs require us to use a single trigger, it's a long story), and the "running" of the trigger.

This bash script was hard to work with and improve, and through the import-run shenanigans actually led to some faulty deploys that caused all kinds of chaos: not great.

However, recently I found a way to pass `substitution` variables as part of a manual trigger operation using the Node.js library for Cloud Build (`runTrigger` with subs passed as part of the request)!

**Problem:** So I'm converting our build utility to Node, which is great, but as far as I can tell there isn't a native way to steam build logs from a running build in the console (except maybe with `exec`, but that feels hacky).

*Am I missing something? Or should I be looking at one of the `logging` libraries?*

I've tried my best scanning Google's docs and APIs ([Cloud Build REST](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest), the [Node client library](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/cloudbuild/latest/cloudbuild/v1.cloudbuildclient#package), etc.) but to no avail.